# Creating 'Independent' Child Bone

Tags: rigging, armature

Suppose I am attempting to make a hinge joint for a box for an armature.

The hinge should only affect the movement of the flap, and move relative to the bone of the box.

Naively, I have set this up by creating two bones: one to control the global translation/rotation/scale of the combined object and a bone to control the local rotation of the flap.

[image: Naive setup]

However, perhaps expectedly, the box deforms with the movement of the hinge. This is not what I want.

[image: Deformation]

I am sure the answer is trivial, but how do I 'divorce' the hinge bone from the control bone so that I can have both a moving flap I can control which moves relative to the box?

[image]

Comment: There's a complete tutorial from Derek Elliot on a folding box animation [here](https://youtu.be/O1em_ijMvUk) which might be of use to you.

Comment: Thank you. While that is helpful, it does not explicitly resolve the example I am struggling with, which is analogous to the one I am actually trying to solve in the project.

Comment: @JackRolph: if you would have watched the tutorial John was recommending you should have noticed that he did parent to empty groups and assigned the faces manually to the vertex groups in contrary to your attempt by using "with automatic weights". For beginners i can only recommend following exactly what the tutor does, else you will fail. Because just a single difference can make the whole scenario fail - except you know exactly what you are doing and what's going on (i know this by my own "often failed"-experience

Answer (score 1):

you have wrong weight paint on the box.

Maybe you know - the bones and the vertex groups get the same name by Blender if you are using "parent with automatic weights". If you check the weight painting of your bone.001 you will see, that the box is colored. That's the reason why bone.001 also moves the box.

So one way to repair that is ...

1. delete vertex group bone.001
2. select the face in edit mode

[image]

3. in object mode first select the box, then shift select the armature
4. go in pose mode, shift select bone.001

[image]

5. press ctrl-p -> choose bone

result:

[image]